# Tensorflow freeze model but backpropagate error and update input layer

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation, softmax

I try to explain my goal.
With a trained model I want to select the output class and update the feeded image.

1. Assign an image to the 'input_layer'.
2. Forward and compute error of 'output_layer' against desired output/class.
3. Backpropagate the error to the 'input_layer' without updating the weights and biases of the net.
4. Update the input layer, the original image, with the backpropagated error.

Some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.gradients` to back propagate to the input layer:

```
...
logits = run_net(image)
g = tf.gradients(logits[target_class], image)
image += g[0] * step
...
```

Good examples of doing this can be found in the [Deep Dream demo code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb) (see for example "Naive feature visualization" or "Multiscale image generation."